# Is Colmar's railway station next to the city center?

Tags: trains, france

I'm thinking about taking a train to Colmar to do some sightseeing there. But is the railway station next to the city center, respectively the old town or is it far away?

Comment: On Google Maps it looks like it's 500-600 m from the old town.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While it is not exactly in old town it isn't far away from what I call tell on [the map](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=Gare+de+Colmar,+Place+de+la+Gare,+Colmar,+France&hl=sv&ll=48.07352,7.352986&spn=0.02532,0.066047&sll=48.07309,7.350583&sspn=0.02532,0.066047&t=h&hq=Gare+de+Colmar,+Place+de+la+Gare,&hnear=Colmar,+Haut-Rhin,+Alsace,+Frankrike&fll=48.069706,7.354317&fspn=0.025322,0.066047&z=15).

The [wiki on Gare Colmar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gare_de_Colmar) also has coordinates.

Comment: Colmar is not in the middle of nowhere as some TGV stations (like [Champagnes-Ardennes station](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gare_de_Champagne-Ardenne_TGV)), if that is what @RoflcoptrException is asking.

Comment: @Vince I was more asking if I can walk from the train station to the old town.

Comment: @RoflcoptrException Yes, and it is a nice walk too (I have been to Colmar by train).